# Nimble - `contain` doesn't accept array of arrays

Tags: swift, quick-nimble

With [Nimble](https://github.com/Quick/Nimble) matchers, if I try something like this:

```
expect([["a"],["b"]]).to(contain([["a"],["b"]]))
```

I get this error:

```
Error:(29, 54) cannot convert value of type 'Predicate<NMBContainer>' to expected argument type 'Predicate<[[String]]>'
```

But this is fine:

```
expect(["a","b"]).to(contain(["a","b"]))
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it and both versions work fine for me. If you are not using `7.1.1` ver - could be a reason to update.